# Gnome 3 proxy settings

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gnome, proxy

If I set my network proxy settings using Gnome 3 Manager in Ubuntu 11.04 System Settings like the following picture:

[image]

Chrome and Firefox are not using those proxy settings when trying to connect to the internet. Any suggestions?

Is there an application like [Proxyfier](http://www.proxifier.com/) for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dconf-editor for setting proxy settings. Firefox will understand them.

[image: Dconf-editor Gnome3]

Answer (score 0):

You can try a chrome extension called ProxySwitchy or ProxySwitchySharp.

Comment: Can you provide more information about exactly what these extensions do, how they're different from each other, and how to obtain them?